# Alternative representation for Perron Frobenius Eigenvalue

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-optimization

While explaining the application of Geometric programming to Minimizing Spectral radius Boyd says that $\lambda_{pf}$ can also be characterized as: 
$\operatorname{inf}\{\lambda|\exists{v}>0, Av\leq\lambda{v}\}$

According to my understanding Perron Frobenius Eigenvalue is the Eigenvalue with largest absolute value. These two definitions seems conflicting to me.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably $A$ is (entrywise) positive or it is both irreducible and nonnegative. By Perron-Frobenius theorem, the spectral radius $\rho(A)$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and there exists a *positive* left eigenvector $u$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\rho(A)$. Now, if $Av\le\lambda v$ for some positive $v$, then $\rho(A)u^Tv=u^TAv\le\lambda u^Tv$, i.e. $\rho(A)\le\lambda$. Therefore $\rho(A)\le\inf\{\lambda\mid\exists v>0,\,Av\le\lambda v\}$. However, as $Av=\rho(A)v$ for the (right) Perron vector of $A$, the inequality is sharp.

Comment: Will I not be able to find some positive v corresponding to all $\lambda$ such that $Av\leq\lambda{v}$? I am asking this because if this is the case then $\lambda{pf}$ will be the smallest $\lambda$....And another thing is will these condition tally with the actual definition of Perron-Frobenius eigenvalue?

Comment: Does this explanation mean that for the $\lambda$ for which I can find $v$ such that $Av\leqλv$(provided the answer to the above question is yes) They will be larger than $\lambda_{pf}$ but their absolute value will be lesser?

Comment: @Shirin Look, the inequality $Av\le\lambda v$, if it holds for $(\lambda,v)$, does not make $(\lambda,v)$ an eigenpair. It is an eigenpair only when **equality** holds. Now, what my answer shows is that $\rho(A)$ is the **only** eigenvalue that has a **positive** eigenvector. It is possible to have some $\lambda>\rho(A)$ and some $v>0$ such that $Av\le\lambda v$, but if this is the case, **strict** inequality must hold and hence $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue. It is also possible for $A$ to have other smaller positive eigenvalues, but these eigenvalues don't have **positive** eigenvectors.

Comment: Thank you......When you say smaller in the last line you mean smaller in terms of absolute value or a regular "smaller then"?

Comment: @Shirin I said "smaller **positive** eigenvalues", so I was talking about only those positive eigenvalues. In this case, the two notions of "smaller" are the same.

Comment: Sorry that was dumb of me!!!